# White space when overflow on iOS browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm quite new to HTML and CSS. I'm currently developing a web page for mobile. and I'm facing an issue is when I drag on the page that is not scrollable, there is white space coming down from the top, on iOS safari or chrome browser.

[image]

I have set my page CSS as follow:

```
.app-view{
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0px;
  overflow-y: hidden!important;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This white space only appears on iOS but not Android. Does anyone know how?

UPDATE:

I've got the answer, i'm using framework7, and there is another layer hiding underneath, when i change that layer to become position:fixed. The problem would go away

Answer (score 1):

maybe there are some not expected margins or paddings in block that contains your `.app-view`, its hard to answer without your markup and other css